# Unlinking my Trailhead account from Partner Community Profile

Tags: trailhead, partner-communities

So the issue is I can't display any of my certifications/trailhead information on my Trailhead community profile and after playing around with the settings and others, I figured it's because my account is linked to a Partner Profile from my previous job which, I assume, they obviously disabled. Actually, when I click on the *Partner Community Access* in my profile, I still see my prior job's email there.

[image: Partner Community Access]

Is there any way to unlink these two accounts? I tried to open a case, but I could not open one with my personal dev account (which I guess makes sense), and I'm not sure if my current company would like me opening one with their instance's account.

Any insight on the issue and how to unlink them?

Thanks!

Comment: Salesforce trailhead team can do it for you. You can email them at trailhead@salesforce.com.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal cool! I'll email them to double check then :) Where did you find that email btw?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal negative. It's a "no-reply" email address. Check here: http://prntscr.com/k8fed8

Comment: Is it possible to have the trailblazer profile completly disconnected with a salesforce account? Or do you need to have a account from salesforce to access it? Just trying to imagine what would happen if i lose my current salesforce account.

Comment: Hi Javier. I managed to find this contact site connected to the topic called "Badges Linked to Trailblazer/Partner Community" I suppose you can get help there https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=article&article=Trailhead-Self-Service-Account-Merge#  (It doesn't link directly but go to : Need help with My Account -> Badges Linked to Trailblazer/Partner Community)

Comment: @user1974566 indeed. They gave a formal answer below, but thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick I'm not sure about that. Nonetheless, to avoid having that problem, make sure to link your Trailblazer profile to Linkdn or Google and in case your dev org expires, you may still have access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar experience myself when I parted ways with a partner after having connected my existing Trailhead Profile with my new Partner Profile they created for me. You'll want to go to this help page [Lost access to my Salesforce User and Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Lost-access-to-my-Salesforce-User-and-Trailhead) where you find a link to [submit a case](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=home).

Before you go there, if you don't already have one, make certain you create a Developer Org that you have access to, to use for your Trailhead and Success Community Profile in the future. Once you arrive at the support page, select "Need help with my Account" in the upper half and down below, select "Badges Linked to Trailblazer/Partner Community".

Once you've done that, a form will appear. Complete all the details about your Partner Community Profile, Company Name, current email address, Trailhead Profile URL, and add all the relevant details you can in the text area below. In the subject line use something like "Lost Access to Partner Community Trailhead Account and Company Email from Job Change". That should provide support with what they need to transfer the account back to your personal email account.

Expect it to take a few days before you hear from them. If it's more than a week, file another support case.

Comment: Yup. This is the only way I've found to do it. Thanks!